# Best Systems for Storing and Organizing Videos/ Projects?

Tags: video, software-recommendation, filming, storage

I’m just getting into video recording/ production and am looking for recommendations on best systems to upload, store, organize, and edit videos. Also want to make sure that the videos are backed up in multiple places. Currently using a Sony Alpha A7III. I love shooting video, but the organization part feels more daunting. Any advice on systems for organization or online classes/ tutorials about getting started?

Comment: The main goal of SE sites is to help people with their specific questions, not so much to help them get started in general. The reason is that the best strategy to learn something is highly individual. General recommendations are problemtic too, as we would need many more details in order to give a good recommendation. Which system works best is highly opinion based. Such questions are better discussed elsewhere, like in a forum, not here because this format is not suited for such discussions.

Comment: Instead, try to describe a specific problem you have, for example "I lose control over which clip belongs to which scene in the script. What can be done to improve that?"

Comment: Digital asset management is an entire industry. People with degrees in library sciences go into the field.